# SQL IF or search statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Everyone,

I might be overthinking this or just suck at SQL. I am using Windows sql server 2016 and trying to create a if statement to be part of search field that will be in my R function. Below is my sql code and I am trying to do a if statement, where I search for a number in a select filed, if not match just list all in that columns.

```
SELECT
df.[Name] AS Farm_Name
, dw.[Name] AS WTG_Name
, dw.[Id] AS WTG_Id     
, fa.[StartTime] AS StartTime
, fa.[EndTime] AS EndTime
, fa.[LocalStartTime] AS LocalStartTime
, fa.[LocalEndTime] AS LocalEndTime
, da.[Code] AS Alarm_Code
, da.[Description] AS Alarm_Description
, fa.[SeverityStart] AS Severity_Start
, fa.[MaintenanceFlag] AS Maintenance_Flag
, da.[Stop] AS Alarm_Stop
, da.[Warning] AS Alarm_Warning
, da.[Maintenance] AS Alarm_Maintenance
, da.[LBA] AS Alarm_LBA    

FROM [DataMart].[FactAlarms10Min] AS fa
INNER JOIN [DataMart].[DimAlarm] AS da
ON fa.[IdAlarm] = da.[Id]
INNER JOIN [DataMart].[DimWTG] AS dw
ON fa.[IdWTG] = dw.[Id]
INNER JOIN [DataMart].[DimFarm] AS df
ON dw.[IdFarm] = df.[Id]

WHERE dw.[Name] IN ('SC4020') -- WTG Name/Number 

IF da.[Code] = 707
    THEN da.[Code] = 707;    
ELSE  da.[Code] > 0);

AND fa.[StartTime] BETWEEN (convert(datetime, '2021-01-01')) AND (convert(datetime, '2021-01-10'))
```

So This is what I am trying to do, search for `da.[Code]`number 707, if no match just show everything in `da.[Code]`. This field `da.[Code]` will be a number from 0 - 1000

Comment: `IF`, in SQL, is a logical flow operator; it can't be used as part of a statement. Perhaps what you want is a `NOT EXISTS`, and an `OR`.

Comment: update your question ad   proper data sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you  wnat select only the rows with da.[Code] = 707  or if not all the rows with  da.[Code] > 0

then you should use

```
SELECT
df.[Name] AS Farm_Name
, dw.[Name] AS WTG_Name
, dw.[Id] AS WTG_Id     
, fa.[StartTime] AS StartTime
, fa.[EndTime] AS EndTime
, fa.[LocalStartTime] AS LocalStartTime
, fa.[LocalEndTime] AS LocalEndTime
, da.[Code] AS Alarm_Code
, da.[Description] AS Alarm_Description
, fa.[SeverityStart] AS Severity_Start
, fa.[MaintenanceFlag] AS Maintenance_Flag
, da.[Stop] AS Alarm_Stop
, da.[Warning] AS Alarm_Warning
, da.[Maintenance] AS Alarm_Maintenance
, da.[LBA] AS Alarm_LBA 

FROM [DataMart].[FactAlarms10Min] AS fa
INNER JOIN [DataMart].[DimAlarm] AS da
ON fa.[IdAlarm] = da.[Id]
INNER JOIN [DataMart].[DimWTG] AS dw
ON fa.[IdWTG] = dw.[Id]
INNER JOIN [DataMart].[DimFarm] AS df
ON dw.[IdFarm] = df.[Id]

WHERE dw.[Name] IN ('SC4020') -- WTG Name/Number 
AND ( da.[Code] = 707 OR  da.[Code] > 0)

AND fa.[StartTime] BETWEEN (convert(datetime, '2021-01-01')) AND (convert(datetime, '2021-01-10'))
```

Comment: Thanks and that was fast. I will try this thanks

Comment: This will always return all rows.

Comment: Yup. It's not the condition you are looking for. It's same as da.code>0. da.code=707 will not be considered.

Comment: Agreed, `a.[Code] = 707` is redundant, if `da.[Code] = 707` is true, then by definition `da.[Code] > 0` is true, and the latter captures more rows so the format is pointless. It's like having `WHERE I = 1 or I > 0`,

Comment: @BB.squared You can do it easily with case in where clause. Please check out my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch out the `IF` with a `CASE` statement, using the `EXISTS` logic as in Larnu's comment:

```
; WITH Alarms
AS (
    SELECT
    df.[Name] AS Farm_Name
    , dw.[Name] AS WTG_Name
    , dw.[Id] AS WTG_Id     
    , fa.[StartTime] AS StartTime
    , fa.[EndTime] AS EndTime
    , fa.[LocalStartTime] AS LocalStartTime
    , fa.[LocalEndTime] AS LocalEndTime
    , da.[Code] AS Alarm_Code
    , da.[Description] AS Alarm_Description
    , fa.[SeverityStart] AS Severity_Start
    , fa.[MaintenanceFlag] AS Maintenance_Flag
    , da.[Stop] AS Alarm_Stop
    , da.[Warning] AS Alarm_Warning
    , da.[Maintenance] AS Alarm_Maintenance
    , da.[LBA] AS Alarm_LBA    
    FROM [DataMart].[FactAlarms10Min] AS fa
    INNER JOIN [DataMart].[DimAlarm] AS da
    ON fa.[IdAlarm] = da.[Id]
    INNER JOIN [DataMart].[DimWTG] AS dw
    ON fa.[IdWTG] = dw.[Id]
    INNER JOIN [DataMart].[DimFarm] AS df
    ON dw.[IdFarm] = df.[Id]
    WHERE dw.[Name] IN ('SC4020') -- WTG Name/Number 
    AND fa.[StartTime] BETWEEN (convert(datetime, '2021-01-01')) AND (convert(datetime, '2021-01-10'))
    )
SELECT *
FROM Alarms
WHERE Alarm_Code = 
    CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM Alarms WHERE Alarm_Code = 707) 
        THEN 707 
        ELSE Alarm_Code 
    END ;
```

Here we're asking for an `Alarm_Code` of 707 if one exists, otherwise give me everything where `Alarm_Code` = `Alarm_Code`, which is everything.

Comment: `;` doesn't go at the start of your statements, or prior to a `WITH`, it just goes at the end of each of your statements.

Comment: Larnu, yes, but it frequently messes up new tsql coders if they have code above their CTE and can't figure out why it isn't working.

Comment: Because the error you get, telling you that the prior statement hasn't been properly terminated, isn't specific enough? 

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write your condition with case when in where clause as below:
(case when da.[Code] = 707 then 707 else da.code end) = da.[Code]
if da.code=707 then where clause will be 707=da.code else it will be da.code=da.code which is true for all the value of da.code.

```
SELECT
df.[Name] AS Farm_Name
, dw.[Name] AS WTG_Name
, dw.[Id] AS WTG_Id     
, fa.[StartTime] AS StartTime
, fa.[EndTime] AS EndTime
, fa.[LocalStartTime] AS LocalStartTime
, fa.[LocalEndTime] AS LocalEndTime
, da.[Code] AS Alarm_Code
, da.[Description] AS Alarm_Description
, fa.[SeverityStart] AS Severity_Start
, fa.[MaintenanceFlag] AS Maintenance_Flag
, da.[Stop] AS Alarm_Stop
, da.[Warning] AS Alarm_Warning
, da.[Maintenance] AS Alarm_Maintenance
, da.[LBA] AS Alarm_LBA 

FROM [DataMart].[FactAlarms10Min] AS fa
INNER JOIN [DataMart].[DimAlarm] AS da
ON fa.[IdAlarm] = da.[Id]
INNER JOIN [DataMart].[DimWTG] AS dw
ON fa.[IdWTG] = dw.[Id]
INNER JOIN [DataMart].[DimFarm] AS df
ON dw.[IdFarm] = df.[Id]

WHERE dw.[Name] IN ('SC4020') -- WTG Name/Number 
and (case when da.[Code] = 707 then 707 else da.code end) = da.[Code] 

AND fa.[StartTime] BETWEEN (convert(datetime, '2021-01-01')) AND (convert(datetime, '2021-01-10'))
```